# How to use node.js in a real time gps tracking application?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, postgresql, gps

I am trying to understand how node.js will fit in my scenario.

Currently, a mobile device sends gps coordinates to a Rails backend thru POST. The mobile device sends it every minute.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/location/
```

My RubyOnRails web app can display the history of locations on a map, no problem with this.

But my experience in nodejs is still in its infancy and I would like to understand how to display a map for real time GPS updates as they come in.

Comment: Postgres LISTEN/NOTIFY with node.js http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html  could be an alternative. Bear in mind there may be a lot of location inserts from different devices on the locations table.  If a particular user wants to listen for only device1 updates, the postgres trigger will notify every insert made into the locations table even by other devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).

Most tutorials show some kind of chat application. In your case the communication is only uni-directional. And your device is not connected through WebSockets, but only POSTs new coordinates without a channel back (device doesn't subscribe to events from server).

Your web-page (showing a Google Maps control) connects to your Node.js server through socket.io and gets new coordinates pushed from your server (`socket.emit`). You have to remember somehow which "new-coordinate" events from devices have to be published to which listening web-clients.

And of course you need an initial list of recent coordinates for your web-page if you want to show not only new coordinates of a device. You could deliver them over sockets as well, but as you will need some kind of authentication maybe a REST call is clearer for first population of devices GPS-track.

So when a device updates its location, you only have to find connected listeners for that device and `emit("new-coordinate", {lat: ..., lng: ..., deviceId: ...}` events to the maps. In the web-page, you receive the events and handle them like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    if (typeof io === 'undefined') {
        return; // socket.io not loaded
    }
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('new-coordinate', function (data) {
        console.log('arrived', data);

        $(document).trigger('new-coordinate', data);

        // or just directly update your map ...

    });

});

</script>
```

**Edit**

As your web-page and the new-coordinate POSTs are delivered through RoR, you have to trigger the events from Ruby to node.js server-side. Basically you could call your node.js app from Ruby via REST, but there are other options like **Redis** pub/sub or [dnode ruby](https://github.com/substack/dnode-ruby).

(comment) *I'd migrate the RoR app to node.js ;-)* (/comment)

Comment: Thanks hgoebl! Actually, your comment from shifting the RoR app to nodejs is not a bad idea!  I might go with the socket.io solution as you recommended. I also found https://github.com/Adrianod/Open-GPS-tracker/blob/master/README.md as reference. Cheers,

Comment: @rupert did you go for socket io at the end? Do you need a handshake on server side perhaps the device loses connection and you need to sync back the history(during reconnecting)? Because normal POST will get a response, unless you fire a handshake via socket upon receiving the update.